# How to hook after an user update has been made in the database in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to synchronize an external database entry when a Wordpress user information is updated.
I started by using the `personal_options_update` and `edit_user_profile_update` hooks that seemed made for it.
But I quickly saw that these hooks are fired before the database update, so I cannot read the updated data from the database in order to update my external database.
I looked at the source code in `/wp-admin/user-edit.php` and didn't find any obvious way to do what I want.
All the solutions that I can think of have drawbacks:

- use the posted data instead of reading the data from the database (not ideal because I would have to redo all the data sanitization and I wouldn't be sure if the database update succeeded or not)
- modify the source code to add my own hook after the database update (not ideal because it could conflict with Wordpress updates)
- store the user ids that need to be updated somewhere and do the synchronization later with a cron job (feels like adding unnecessary complexity)

Would by any chance someone have a better idea ?

Comment: Check out [`profile_update`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/profile_update/) and [`user_register`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/). They get called here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/fcc79f847adf0d5467cae4be44152d1cec585f79/wp-includes/user.php#L2106

Comment: Thanks @chris-haas, I just checked `profile_update` and it seems to indeed work like a charm ! Do you want to post your comment as answer so that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two hooks you are looking for are [`profile_update`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/profile_update/) and [`user_register`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/). The are both called [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/fcc79f847adf0d5467cae4be44152d1cec585f79/wp-includes/user.php#L2106) with the former being used post-update, and the latter being used post-insert.

Comment: `profile_update` also triggers when using the Add New User admin screen.